# Unable to link words in a paragraph - Step 12 in FreeCodeCamp.org exercise

Tags: html

In the exercise of freecodecamp.org I am trying to complete step 12 im html. You need to link words in a paragraph, but only the words "cat photos". I can't find the mistake but it would be nice if someone would describe the mistake and show it to me.
Here's the code:

```
´´´
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>CatPhotoApp</h1>
    <main>
      <h2>Cat Photos</h2>
      <!-- TODO: Add link to cat photos -->
      <p>Click here to view more <a href="https://freecatphotoapp.com">cat photos.</p>
      <a href="https://freecatphotoapp.com"></a>
      <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/cat-photo-app/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
´´´
```

Comment: You didn't close your anchor tag with `</a>`. And you also have an empty link after it that seems unnecessary

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you opened a second anchor tag instead of closing your first one.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>CatPhotoApp</h1>
    <main>
      <h2>Cat Photos</h2>
      <p>Click here to view more <a href="https://freecatphotoapp.com">cat photos</a>.</p>
      <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/cat-photo-app/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a couple of tries to figure it out, it is more of a simpler task than i thought. the key is to only display "see more cat photos in our gallery"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).